# Add border in profile picture uploader in Android.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-picture, uploader

After [the new feature for directly uploading profile picture is introduced](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/) while changing profile picture in [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com), I found that the picture uploader does not have border around. And it is harming my precious eyes.

> [image]

It should have a border like this:

[image]

PS: I don't have idea for other Stack Exchange sites.

Browser: Google Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.52 m), Also in Firefox 17.0.1

**Edit**: While I was checking on other sites, I found in [StackApps.com](http://stackapps.com) that there is a left alignment on that uploader. Which is definitely a bug. See this:

> [image]

Comment: Perhaps if it's only affecting Android.SE it's a better fit to be reported directly on meta.android.se?

Comment: @Rory - I don't have idea if it is *only* affecting Android.SE. That why I asked here.

Comment: How on earth is this question off-topic on **MAIN SE Meta**?

Comment: What browser? Do you see border on other sites? (e.g. here on Meta) For the record, I [see it fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kD2pq.png) on that site..

Comment: @sha - OP's talking about the **profile picture uploader**... I was also confused for a sec :P

Comment: @Lix but isn't it the same uploader?! At least here on Meta it appears to be the same, both have same class `wmd-prompt-dialog` which take the border from "all.css" file.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yes I am talking about *new profile picture uploader*.  That's why I have shown pictures of both uploader. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - And Browser: Chrome (Version 24.0.1312.52 m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this will be rolling out with the next build.

Comment: More to help you. I found this issue only on Android and Stack App from [these sites](http://stackexchange.com/users/1452838/hims056?tab=accounts) (I tried in all accounts.) :)